# Make dependency write to the main log file

Tags: java, android, log4j

I'm developing an Android app that writes to a log file using [android-log4j](https://code.google.com/p/android-logging-log4j/). The android app has a dependency that also needs to write to this log. This dependency (which is also written by our team) is a maven project with these log dependencies required:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Is there a way to make the dependency jar to write its logs to the main log of the Android app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to fix this configuration.

Since android-log4j and slf4j are two different logging components, what we did is to create a log wrapper that is injected to the dependency. I know this is only valid when you own the dependency but it's a workaround worth checking. The log wrapper calss:

```
public interface LogWrapper {

    public void debug(String message);
    public void debug(String message, Throwable t);

    public void info(String message);
    public void info(String message, Throwable t);

    public void warn(String message);
    public void warn(String message, Throwable t);

    public void error(String message);
    public void error(String message, Throwable t);

    public LogWrapper createNewLogger(Class<?> tag);

}
```

Since we want a new logger for each class in the dependency, we used a factory class:

```
public class LoggerFactory {

    private LogWrapper logger;

    public LoggerFactory(LogWrapper logger){
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public LogWrapper getLogger(Class<?> tag){
        if(logger!=null)
            return logger.createNewLogger(tag);
    }
}
```

The android side implements this LogWrapper and sends it the dependency (called LogReceiver) via its constructor:

```
public class LogReceiver {
    protected LogWrapper log;

    public LogReceiver(LoggerFactory logFactory) {
        log = logFactory.getLogger(getClass());
        log.info("A log call");
    }

}
```

On the android side we can implement the log to use android-log4j, LogCat or any other logging tool that we want.
This might be an overkill, but it did what we wanted it to. Hope it helps anyone.